# How to make a method that will get text content and colors to add text with colors to RichTextBox control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

Instead typing this in many places in the code :

```cs
TextRange rangeOfText1 = new TextRange(RichTextBoxLogger.Document.ContentEnd, RichTextBoxLogger.Document.ContentEnd);
rangeOfText1.Text = "Test";
rangeOfText1.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow);
rangeOfText1.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
```

I tried to create a method that I will be able to use all along the code in many places:

```cs
private void RichTextBoxAddText(string TextContent, Brushes ForeGroundColor, FontWeights FontWeightType)
{
    TextRange rangeOfText1 = new TextRange(RichTextBoxLogger.Document.ContentEnd, RichTextBoxLogger.Document.ContentEnd);
    rangeOfText1.Text = "Test";
    rangeOfText1.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow);
    rangeOfText1.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
}
```

But I'm not sure if I'm using the right way with getting the `Brushes` and the `FontWeights` the second problem is that I'm getting error:

> CS0721    `FontWeights`: static types cannot be used as parameters

Comment: Your `FontWeights` error is due to using it as the type in your function's parameters. You should actually be using `FontWeight` for the parameter type. Also, though the `Brushes` type is not static, you probably don't want to use `Brushes` as the parameter type, and instead use `SolidColorBrush`.

Comment: @quaabaam i changed it and it's now fine. but hwen i'm trying to use the method for example like this RichTextBoxSetText("Canceled!", Color.red; the Color don't have any red/Red property. how can i use a Color like in winforms Color.red for example ? and the fontweight i have to make a variable instance first time to use it ?

Comment: @quaabaam i see that for the color i need to use Colors like Colors.Red is that right ? and how do i use the FontWeight ?

Comment: Yes, the easiest way is to just use the predefined colors, e.g. `Colors.Red`. It's similar for `FontWeight`, just use the predefined font weights, e.g. `FontWeight.Bold`. Here's a link to the predefined weights you can reference, [FontWeights Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.fontweights?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an extension method:

```cs
public static class TextRangeExt
{
    public static void RichTextBoxAddText(this TextRange range, string text, 
        SolidColorBrush foregroundColor, 
        FontWeight fontWeight)
    {
        range.Text = text;
        range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, foregroundColor);
        range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, fontWeight);
    }
}
```

And now you can use the method like:

```
var doc = RichTextBoxLogger.Document;
new TextRange(doc.ContentEnd, doc.ContentEnd).RichTextBoxAddText("Test", Brushes.Red, FontWeights.Bold);
```